Find matrix given matrix times its transpose
I thought of this problem: How would you find a matrix A such that:
AAᵀ=
[14 0 12]
[0  5  0]
[12 0 16]?

I've tried multiplying a matrix A with entries a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, and i together, but some entries of the resulting matrix are similar to "ad+be+cf" or "d²+e²+f²". Then trying to solve the equations, for example ag+bh+ci=12, would be pretty difficult.
How would this be solved otherwise?

Think about the row vectors of $A$. What are their lengths? Are the first and third orthogonal to the second?

Almost sounds like you want a Cholesky factorization, sort of.

well, first do $$ \left(
\begin{array}{rr}
14 & 12 \
12 & 16 \
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Did you find my answer satisfactory?

One answer would be the Cholesky decomposition. In general, $A$ isn't unique; there are many possible answers that would fit your criteria.
EDIT:
I think I want to mention another way to do this, namely eigendecomposition. With this decomposition you can find:
$$AA^T=Q\Lambda Q^T$$
Here $Q$ is orthogonal and has the eigenvectors in it's columns and $\Lambda$ is diagonal and has the corresponding eigenvalues. Then you can have $A=Q\sqrt\Lambda$ where you get the square root of $\Lambda$ by simply taking the square roots of its diagonal elements.

I suggested beginning with
$$
\left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
a & b \\ 
c & d \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
a & c \\ 
b & d \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
14 & 12 \\ 
12 & 16 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
or $$  a^2 + b^2 = 14 \; , \; \; ac+bd = 12  \; , \; \; c^2 + d^2 = 16$$
Drawing a picture in the plane, this means I can take a vector $(a,b)$  of squared length $14,$  a vector $(c,d)$  of squared length $16,$    with their dot product $12,$  meaning the angle between them must be $ \arccos \frac{3}{\sqrt{14}}, $   approximately $36.7^\circ$

As in the diagram, I  just picked $(c,d) = ( 4,0).$  Then taking $(a,b)$ in the first quadrant, we see that $a = 3,$  from which we find $b = \sqrt 5.$
Giving
$$
\left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
3 & \sqrt 5 \\ 
4 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
3 & 4 \\ 
\sqrt 5 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
14 & 12 \\ 
12 & 16 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$
